# Quadtratic variation of a martingale and its derivative

Tags: probability, martingales, quadratic-variation

If I have a martingale $M_t$ and I know its quadratic variation $A_t$.

Is there a connection between $\frac{d}{dt}M_t$ and $A_t$?
Could you give me a book reference?

Thank you very much

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\frac{d}{dt} M_t$? In general, the derivative does not exist (in the classical sense).

Comment: From Ito's formula I know that if $X_t$ is a Markov process and $L$ is itts generator i have: $f(X_t)=f(X_0)+\int_0^t Lf(X_s)ds+M_t$                                where $M_t$ is a martingale

Comment: I need to compute $\frac{d}{dt}f(X_t)$ and so $\frac{d}{dt}M_t$

Comment: I don't know exactly in which sense... I would like to write something like this

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}f(X_t)=Lf(X_t)+\frac{d}{dt}M_t$

Comment: Just consider the case that $M$ is e.g. a Brownian motion, then this expression doesn't make sense. Actually, I think that you want to compute $$\frac{d}{dt} \mathbb{E}f(X_t)$$ and not $$\frac{d}{dt} f(X_t).$$

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I'm a little bit confused about it, but I don't think so. If I compute $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbb{E}f(X_t)$ I will have that $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbb{E}(M_t)=0$.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Comment: Instead I want to study the contribution of the martingale that should be important (even though in mean is $0$).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :-)